# How to determine lossless decomposition if no FD is known?

Tags: database, lossless

The table below R(A, B, C, D, E) with no known FD. It decomposes into R1(A, B, C, D) and R2(A, C, E). How do I find out if this is lossless decomposition or not?

```
Table:

A  |  B  |  C |  D  |  E  |
___________________________

10 | 1a1 | k1 | s13 |  a  |

50 | 2b2 | m4 | e25 |  b  |

10 | 3c3 | k1 | b53 |  c  |

20 | 4d4 | g2 | z86 |  d  |
```

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem No, I have a test tomorrow and I'm trying out questions. I am able to do it if FDs are given but not without.

Comment: Well here clearly `(B,D,E)` does not depend on `(A,C)` since `(A,C)=(10,k1)` occurs twice.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sorry, I'm still stuck